# .net real time stream processing - needed huge and fast RAM buffer

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management

The application I'm developing communicates with an digital audio device, which is capable of sending 24 different voice streams at the same time. 
The device is connected via USB, using FTDI device (serial port emulator) and D2XX Drivers (basic COM driver is to slow to handle transfer of 4.5Mbit).

Basically the application consist of 3 threads:

Main thread - GUI, control, ect.

Bus reader - in this thread data is continuously read from the device and saved to a file buffer (there is no logic in this thread)

Data interpreter - this thread reads the data from file buffer, converts to samples, does simple sample processing and saves the samples to separate wav files. 


The reason why I used file buffer is that I wanted to be sure that I won't loose any samples. The application doesn't use recording all the time, so I've chosen this solution because it was safe.

The application works fine, except that buffered wave file generator is pretty slow. For 24 parallel records of 1 minute, it takes about 4 minutes to complete the recording. I'm pretty sure that eliminating the use of hard drive in this process will increase the speed much.

The second problem is that the file buffer is really heavy for long records and I can't clean this up 
until the end of data processing (it would slow down the process even more).

For RAM buffer I need at lest 1GB to make it work properly. 

What is the best way to allocate such a big amount of memory in .NET? I'm going to use this memory in 2 threads so a fast synchronization mechanism needed. I'm thinking about a cycle buffer: one big array, the Bus Reader saves the data, the Data Interpreter reads it. What do you think about it?

[edit]
Now for buffering I'm using classes BinaryReader and BinaryWriter based on a file.

Comment: Have you considered a smaller buffer and periodic flush-to-disks???

Comment: How can it speed up the process? Data Interpreter needs to read the data from the file anyway.

Comment: You cannot create a 1GB byte[] array on a 32-bit operating system.  No problem on a 64-bit OS.  And 10 arrays of 100MB each is rarely a problem on 32-bit.

Comment: You most assuredly can create a 1GB byte[] array on a 32-bit operating system. The buffer allocation limit is a signed 32-bit integer (2GB), although allocating a full 2GB buffer will cause your process to run out of memory unless you've set the IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE and 4GT flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to put together a wrapper class that manages a single byte[] buffer and parcels out temporary locks for data ranges using fixed-size memory streams. Essentially, you define your buffer once, and anytime you want to work with it, you request a lock object from the ConcurrentBuffer class. The lock contains a MemoryStream which is guaranteed to have exclusive access to the index ranges you specified when you requested the lock until you release it.

I've thrown together a simple example that should provide you with a good starting point:

```
public class ConcurrentBuffer
{
    private readonly byte[] buffer;

    internal byte[] GetBuffer() { return buffer; }

    private List<BufferLock> locks = new List<BufferLock>();

    public ConcurrentBuffer(int bufferSize)
    {
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    }

    public BufferLock AcquireLock(int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        if (startIndex < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex");
        if (startIndex > endIndex || endIndex >= buffer.Length) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("endIndex");
        lock (buffer)
        {
            foreach (var l in locks)
            {
                if (!(endIndex < l.StartIndex || startIndex > l.EndIndex))
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            var bl = new BufferLock(startIndex, endIndex, this);
            locks.Add(bl);
            return bl;
        }
    }

    public void ReleaseLock(BufferLock lck)
    {
        lock (buffer)
        {
            locks.Remove(lck);
        }
    }

    public class BufferLock
    {
        public int StartIndex { get; private set; }
        public int EndIndex { get; private set; }
        public ConcurrentBuffer TargetBuffer { get; private set; }
        public MemoryStream Stream { get; private set; }

        internal BufferLock(int startIndex, int endIndex, ConcurrentBuffer buffer)
        {
            StartIndex = startIndex;
            EndIndex = endIndex;
            TargetBuffer = buffer;
            Stream = new MemoryStream(buffer.GetBuffer(), startIndex, endIndex - startIndex, true);
        }

        public void Release()
        {
            Stream.Dispose();
            TargetBuffer.ReleaseLock(this);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConcurrentBuffer cb = new ConcurrentBuffer(32000);

        byte[] myData = { 32, 13, 53, 29, 50 };

        // l1 will acquire a lock
        var l1 = cb.AcquireLock(0, 50); 
        if (l1 != null) l1.Stream.Write(myData, 0, myData.Length);

        // l2 will fail because l1 has part of its range locked
        var l2 = cb.AcquireLock(30, 70);
        if (l2 != null) l2.Stream.Write(myData, 0, myData.Length);

        l1.Release();

        // l3 will succeed at locking because l1 has been released
        var l3 = cb.AcquireLock(40, 5000);
        if (l3 != null)
        {
            while (l3.Stream.Position + myData.Length <= l3.Stream.Length)
            {
                l3.Stream.Write(myData, 0, myData.Length);
            }
        }

        l3.Release();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```